# Wrong time while getting from full date

Tags: javascript, datetime, react-native, momentjs

I am working on sample react-native app. 
I am using moment.js to convert time to AM and PM representations.
My data is:

```
{
    "start_date":"2017-09-29T18:29:59.000Z",
    "end_date":"2017-09-29T19:29:59.000Z"
}
```

When converting the `start_date` and `end_date` to 12 hour clock format (AM/PM) using moment().format('LT'), I get the wrong time i.e. 11:59 PM for `start_date` - 12:59 AM for `end_date`.

How do I get the right time and format?

Comment: the `Z` in `2017-09-29T18:29:59.000Z` means UTC time - are you on UTC time?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on [UTC+5:30 time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B05:30)

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct, since you are passing `2017-09-29T18:29:59.000Z` it will turn to 11:59pm under your locale.

But LT as a format will really just return the time. Try using `MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss a` for the format string.

You can check more here at the [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

I also made [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99vn6qaj/1/) for you to play around with.